# Access GUI item, via sender?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox, progress-bar

OK, here's my situation :

- I've got a ListBox populated using Bindings (a class with a list of items)
- Each item in the ListBox contains some TextBlocks, a ProgressBar and a Button
- After clicking the Button, the proper event is fired and I'm able to retrieve the "object" being clicked through `((Button)sender).DataContext`

**The question :**

- After clicking the button, how am I supposed to access the UI controls of the item being clicked and e.g. "bind" a progress value to the "selected" item's progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the button (by casting `sender`), then you can access the other controls by browsing the visual tree (retrieving the parent of the button by using button.Parent, then the children, and so on...). But it's a bad idea to do so because it creates a strong dependency between your UI and your code (when you change the UI, you have to change the code).

Rather, use databindings to set the controls properties, and just modify your model from the code behind. Basically, you already know how to retrieve the model by using `((Button)sender).DataContext`, why don't you bind the progress bar to a property of that object?

If you can't modify the model or don't want to add a "Progress" property on it, you can use a wrapper:

```
public class Wrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyModel Model { get; set; }
    public double Progress { get; set; }
    // etc...
}
```

Then just bind these objects to your listbox.

Comment: Really interesting suggestion. Basically, you got me in the "if you don't want to add a 'Progress' property on it" part... I'll see how I could make that work with a Wrapper, as you suggested! :-)